# Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy not showing

Tags: .htaccess, caching, cache-control, lighthouse

I have set up cache-control in my .htaccess file. However, when I check my site on Lighthouse in Chrome, I still get the message ”
Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy” and it lists several pages that are not cached. At least it turned from red to orange.

How can I fix this?

```
# Cache Control and Enable CORS
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|jpg|gif|png|pdf|swf|svg|svgz|ico|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|webp)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault  "access plus 1 month"
    Header set Cache-Control "public, immutable, max-age=2628000, s-maxage=2628000"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

[image]

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue, did you find a solution?